# Generate centered thumbnail from first frame of GIF with ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have the following method to generate a thumbnail. It takes any dimensions and converts it to a 600 x 450 image, centered.

```
private function generateThumbnail ($ext, $name) {

    if ($ext === ".png"){
      exec('convert -define png:size=1200x900 '.$this->file.'  -thumbnail 600x450^ -gravity center -extent 600x450  '.$name);
      exec("optipng -o2 -q " . $name);
    } else {
      exec('convert -define jpeg:size=1200x900 '.$this->file.'  -thumbnail 600x450^ -gravity center -extent 600x450  '.$name);
      $img = new Imagick($name);
      $img->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
      $img->setImageCompressionQuality(97);
      $img->stripImage();
      $img->writeImage($name);
      $img->destroy();
    }

}
```

The problem arises when generating a thumbnail from a GIF. It doesn't generate an image from the first frame. One GIF just had a blank image (transparent), another had strange colors/quality.

How do I generate a thumbnail the first frame of a GIF, centered?

Comment: Just a question but I am wondering why you start off with Imagemagick using exec() and the command line then drop into the Imagick API.

Comment: Not sure I understand why you are mixing commandline with Imagick, but in general, you can specify the frame number in square brackets after the filename, so for the first frame of a GIF, you would use `image.gif[0]`.

Comment: @Bonzo I wasn't sure if you could do the command line ones with the API, as I found the answers here on SO using the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do them with the API but I do not use it as it is limited. But it looks like you still need to use the command line for the optipng program anyway so I would have carried on with the command line.

Anyway back to your problem; how do you know the first frames of the gif are not a transparent image or a strange image?

As @Mark Setchell said you should be able to specify a specific frame with input.gif[0] and I would try that with a different number and see what you get.
I am not an animation use but you should be able to see the gif frames with -coalesce. Anthony has some examples on his site: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#coalesce
This should give you an idea of the frames in the gif:

```
montage script_k.gif -coalesce \
          -tile x1 -frame 4 -geometry '+2+2' \
          -background none -bordercolor none coalesce_k_montage.gif
```

You can see how you gif file is made and perhaps go for the second or third frame rather than the first.